# ViewModel fica NULL quando efetuado um submit na View Principal - Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Tenho uma ViewModel (`FilialViewModel`) que possui uma propriedade do tipo `PessoaViewModel`. A View principal está atrelada à FilialViewModel e sempre que eu faço um submit, a propriedade do tipo PessoaViewModel fica `NULL`. Isso se dá pelo fato de que, no momento que chamo a PartialView Pessoa, Eu passo FilialViewModel.PessoaViewModel... Ao efetuar o submit, são carregados apenas os campos de FilialViewModel... Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

```
public class FilialViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int PessoaFilialId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Tipo de Filial")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Escolha um Tipo de Filial")]
    public FilialTipo FilialTipo { get; set; }

    public PessoaViewModel PessoaViewModel { get; set; }

}

public class PessoaViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Natureza")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Escolha uma Natureza")]
    public PessoaNatureza PessoaNatureza { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Natureza")]
}
```

View Filial:

```
@model Retaguarda.Application.ViewModels.Filial.FilialViewModel
@{

}

<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-body container-fluid pt-5 pl-15 pr-15">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <vc:summary />
           @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Pessoa/_Pessoa.cshtml", Model.PessoaViewModel)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

View Pessoa:

```
@model Retaguarda.Application.ViewModels.Pessoa.PessoaViewModel
@using Retaguarda.Domain.Enuns.Pessoa
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Pessoa";
}

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id, new { @class = "hidden-id" })
<div class="col-md-2">
    <label asp-for="PessoaNatureza" class="control-label">Natureza</label>
    <select id="pessoaNatureza" data-modal="" asp-for="PessoaNatureza" asp-items="Model.PessoasNaturezas" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="PessoaNatureza" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Policy = "CanWriteFilialData")]
[Route("filial-gerenciar/cadastrar-novo")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(FilialViewModel filialViewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(filialViewModel);
    _filialAppService.Register(filialViewModel);

    if (IsValidOperation())
        ViewBag.Sucesso = "Filial cadastrada!";
    // return Json(new { success = true, message = "Pessoa Excuída!" });
    return View(filialViewModel);

}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PessoaViewModel` vem nulo por que em nenhum momento ela foi instanciada.

Pode resolver isso instanciando em um [construtor](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors):

```
public class FilialViewModel
{
    public FilialViewModel()
    {
        PessoaViewModel = new PessoaViewModel();
    }

    [Key]
    public int PessoaFilialId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Tipo de Filial")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Escolha um Tipo de Filial")]
    public FilialTipo FilialTipo { get; set; }

    public PessoaViewModel PessoaViewModel { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Obrigado @George Wurthmann!